# Sending data fields through request.post

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs  #importing the required libraries
from urllib.request import  urlopen
import requests
urls1="https://www.makemytrip.com/hotels/" #initial url which contains the form where we could give our preferences.

#passing the data parameters
data={'checkin': '08152020',
'city': 'CTGOI',
'checkout': '08162020',
'roomStayQualifier': '2e0e',
'locusId': 'CTGOI',
'country': 'IN',
'locusType': 'city',
'searchText': 'Goa, India',
'visitorId': '5c68c2fb-0551-4ef2-8dae-1a55bb744e66'
}
req=requests.post(urls1,data, headers={'User-Agent': 'XYZ/3.0'})
page_soup = bs(req.content,"html.parser")
print(page_soup)
```

Actually I want to scrape hotels which come under the above mentioned data fields, that is why I am sending the data parameter with the requests.post method to the initial url,so that when I receive  the response object, I will get the content of the next page which will contain the hotels which fall under the above required criteria.

Comment: pleas format you code. And there is no question here

Comment: Hi Sir, actually I want to send additional data like check in ,checkout, place,etc through the requets.post method, so that when that is done the response object which I will get will contain all the hotels list mentioned in the data parameter so that I could scrape it.

Comment: Can you update the question by writing what problems you are facing with the same?
It will also help if you can display the print output.
You can use something like this to extract:

page_soup.find("input", {"id": "some_id"})["value"]

Comment: Bendik Knapstad , the page soup contains the content of the initial url only, which I do not want.I want the content of the next page when I click on search(after filling the details like place,checkin,chekout time ,etc.)

Comment: Thankyou everyone for the suggestions really appreciate a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website that you are scraping uses the GET method to perform searches.

It also uses a different URL for hotel searches, https://www.makemytrip.com/hotels/hotel-listing/

Modifying your example a bit to apply the GET request instead of the POST request, we are able to obtain the hotel listing results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
# setting a "browser" header seems to be required for this site.

data = {'checkin': '08192020',
        'city': 'CTGOI',
        'checkout': '08202020',
        'roomStayQualifier': '2e0e',
        'locusId': 'CTGOI',
        'country': 'IN',
        'locusType': 'city',
        'searchText': 'Goa, India',
        'visitorId': 'aaab4f61-2069-4033-bb97-0791f0f70'}

url = 'https://www.makemytrip.com/hotels/hotel-listing/'

# adding the params argument and supplying the dictionary of search data formats the resulting URL into something that makemytrip.com can understand. 
# adding a timeout just in case makemytrip.com doesn't respond
req = requests.get(url, params=data, headers=headers, timeout=5)


page_soup = bs(req.content,'html.parser')

# this finds all the divs in the result with a class name of "listingRow".  
listing_results = page_soup.findAll('div', class_='listingRow')

# this results array can then be looped through to find more details about each listing.
for listing in listing_results:
    print(listing.find("p", itemprop="name").getText())
```

Comment: Thankyou @Matt Dale, for the detailed explanation of the code which thus solves my query, appreciate the effort. Thankyou Sir!

Comment: how  you came to know about the different url which the website uses,also when I click on the url I am not getting redirected, although. the code  is running smoothly

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that.  I went to the site and performed a search in my browser.  After pressing the search button, the browser redirects to the /hotel-listing/ URL with the query parameters.  
You can also see this by using the Chrome dev tools Network tab and watching the requests happen as you perform a search.